# How to catch an id from sfUser?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, sfguard

I'm working with symfony 1.4 & i use sfDoctrineGuardPlugin as a tool for authentifications.

I want to catch the Id of user in order te store it in my table.

After a small research, I guess I have to use that expression : `getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId()`.

What i looking for is how to invest that expression for my target.

Comment: Can you expand on "invest that expression for my target"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: "What i looking for is how to invest that expression for my target." Yups, elaborate please....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if the user is authenticated, yes, you can use:

```
// inside an action
$id = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();

// inside a template
$id = $sf_user->getGuardUser()->getId();
```

If the user is not authenticated, it'll throw an error.

Comment: it's what I'm using, the same instruction, but what I'm looking for is how to save that object which has $id as one of properties? that mean that how can I modify my action to do that ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "one of properties"? What different objects are you dealing with?

Comment: I want to hide that field(id) from my form & When I click save, it must be saved automatiquely. So what should I modify in my action to do that using : $id = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();  for the object which i try to save

Comment: To be honest, I'd recommend that you take a look at the documentation for this. There's more than one part to your question, and also several ways of doing it. I recommend that you have a look at the Jobeet tutorial.

Comment: Jobeet Tutorial is so huge, do you have a special link for that(exactly when)

Answer (score 3):

Depends from where you are calling.

From the 'view':

```
echo $sf_user->getAttribute('user_id', null, 'sfGuardSecurityUser' );
echo $sf_user->getUsername();
```

From the 'controller' (as mentioned by Tom above):

```
echo $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId();
echo $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getUsername();
```

(First line is 'id', second is 'username')