# How do I get current user id in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to catch an id from sfUser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028718/how-to-catch-an-id-from-sfuser)

How can I get the current logged in user's id in symfony(1.4.17)?

I tried that get guard user thing, but not working. I just wanna have the current user id in a variable.

Comment: *I tried that get guard user thing* - Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the id attrubute during the log-in procedure

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute("id", <your id>);
```

and then retrieve it

```
$this->getUser()->getAttribute("id");
```